Translate "el secreto"
Salvete!
I am looking for a translation of the phrase "el secreto" in Spanish, or "the secret" in English into Latin.
Google translate seems to suggest "secretum" but that does not seem right. Is it not missing an article accompanying the name?
For context, I'm trying to translate the name of this artwork
Thank you in advance, Valete!

Could you elaborate on what sort of "secret" you mean here?

The artwork depicts Eros whispering a secret into Venus ears. So in this context the secret is the information being exchanged. Did that help? Thank you in advance @Draconis

secretum actually sounds like a fine suggestion. Latin has no articles.

secretum used (by others too) but also by Pliny,  Letters Book III  Section 6   http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=urn:cts:latinLit:phi1318.phi001.perseus-lat1:3.1.6  quam dulce secretum!  How sweet (a) secret!   With the article (a) not in Latin  inserted into the English. It's possible to use demonstrative pronouns to change meaning,  hoc secretum.    this secret,    illud secretum  that secret

Thank you both for your answers! I really like "hoc secretum", which I think emphasizes that it is a specific secret being shared, just by having "this" in there.
I've also come across "Arcanum", which could also work in this context?
